# Explicitwait doesn't work

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests and for some reason my explicit wait does not seem to wait the length of time I'm telling it. I have a base class that I inherit where I declare the variable.

When I run my code well before 20 seconds are up it says "The remote server returned an error (404) Not found".

This happens because it doesn't wait the length I'm telling it to

My code is as follows

```
 public class WordBaseClass



   {


    public string wordId = OfficeVersion.Word();
    public const string AppDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";
    public static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> wordSession;


    public static string exception;

    public static DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    public static WebDriverWait webDriverWait;

    protected virtual void SetUp()
    {

        try
        {


            appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", wordId);

            var initialSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(AppDriverUrl), appCapabilities);

            var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability("app", "Root");
            wordSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(AppDriverUrl), capabilities);

            CommonMethods.keyCheck(wordSession);

            webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(wordSession, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            CommonMethods.ExceptionHandler("WinApp Driver failed to load Word", new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), wordSession);
        }
}
}
```

My test class

```
public class Word:WordBaseClass
{

    [TestMethod]

    public void newWordDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            base.SetUp();
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("Blank document"))).Click();
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("New"))).Click();
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("A  Agreements"))).Click();
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("A Confidentiality Agreement"))).Click();
            CommonMethods.IsElementDisplayed(wordSession, new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), "CreateErrorIcon", "Error appeard while selecting the A Confidentiality Agreemnet button");
            webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(wordSession.FindElementByName("OK"))).Click();
            CommonMethods.IsElementDisplayed(wordSession, new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), "CreateErrorIcon", "Error appeard while selecting the OK button");


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            CommonMethods.ExceptionHandler("Couldn't find element", new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), wordSession);
        }
        TearDown();

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the Stacktrace

Comment: @ChandraShekhar what do you mean by structure? The code I have used for the test is there. Would you like to see an image of the inspect tool?

Comment: Have you tried using a while or for loop with a Thread.sleep call for comparison? Just to see if you stay for the 20 seconds or if it errors out before?

Comment: @socalcheesehead It's defiantly not waiting as I changed it to 60 seconds just to test and it still says `error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."` However when I debug it I can see the timeout is set to 60 seconds

Comment: What you're saying is in that instance it doesn't wait 60 seconds before it throws the exception right? If so, what happens if instead of using WebDriverWait you use a while loop? Do you get the same behavior?

Comment: I have been advised not to use threading when using selenium as it can waste time and depends on the power of the PC that is running the tests as if it's a slow PC the sleep time would have to be longer but if it's a fast PC you are wasting time. What do you think?

Comment: I agree and I'm not suggesting that you use that long term, i suggested it merely as a test to see if you use a while loop with a Thread.Sleep(1000) if you actually make it to your 20 seconds mark or if it errors before that with a different exception.